# C# Get specific object from JSON response using HttpClient

Tags: c#, json, parsing, httpclient

I'm trying to parse json from the google maps api for geocoding.

The JSON is:

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "1600",
           "short_name" : "1600",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
           "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Mountain View",
           "short_name" : "Mountain View",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
           "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "California",
           "short_name" : "CA",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "94043",
           "short_name" : "94043",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 37.4224277,
           "lng" : -122.0843288
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 37.4237766802915,
              "lng" : -122.0829798197085
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 37.4210787197085,
              "lng" : -122.0856777802915
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  }
 ],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

I'm only interested in the `location` object with the latitude and longitude and would like to know how to navigate the json object tree within c# to retrieve them from a HttpContent as response from a GetAsync on a HttpClient.
The following code fragment illustrates how my request is done.

```
public async Task<Coordinates> GeoCode(string address) 
{
      HttpClient client= new HttpClient();
      var baseUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";
      var addressEncoded = WebUtility.UrlEncode(address);
      var response= await client.GetAsync(baseUrl + addressEncoded);

      if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
           //read location ...
      }
}
```

How might I read the location object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I usually do it. (I saved your json object into D:/json.txt)

```
 var json = File.ReadAllText("D:/json.txt");
 var results = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("results") as JArray;

foreach (var result in results)
{
    var geometryEntry = result.SelectToken("geometry.location");
    var longitude = geometryEntry.Value<double>("lat");
    var latitude = geometryEntry.Value<double>("lng");

    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", longitude, latitude);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to deserialize JSON to typed classes and other use *dynamic* types.

[Using JSON.NET for dynamic JSON parsing](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing)

> The JSON string represents an object with three properties which is parsed into a JObject class and cast to dynamic. Once cast to dynamic I can then go ahead and access the object using familiar object syntax.

```
public void JValueParsingTest()
{
    var jsonString = @"{""Name"":""Rick"",""Company"":""West Wind"",
                        ""Entered"":""2012-03-16T00:03:33.245-10:00""}";

    dynamic json = JValue.Parse(jsonString);

    // values require casting
    string name = json.Name;
    string company = json.Company;
    DateTime entered = json.Entered;

    Assert.AreEqual(name, "Rick");
    Assert.AreEqual(company, "West Wind");            
}
```

Comment: Thanks , the dynamic solution looks interesting , any idea how to parse to dynamic from the response.content ?

Comment: Just use response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() to get json as System.String and pass it to Parse method.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, to retrieve coordinates you could use strongly typed object provided by [Geocoding](https://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net) package:

```
public async Task<Coordinates> GeoCode(string address) 
{
    GoogleGeocoder geocoder = new GoogleGeocoder();
    IEnumerable<GoogleAddress> addresses = await geocoder.GeocodeAsync(address);    

    GoogleAddress first = addresses?.FirstOrDefault();

    return first == null
        ? null
        : new Coordinates
        {
            Latitude = first.Coordinates.Latitude,
            Longitude = first.Coordinates.Longitude
        };
}
```